# How to export all logs from stackdriver into big query through terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, terraform-provider-gcp

I'll preface this by saying I am very new to GCP, stackdriver and big query.

I'm attempting to have all logs within stackdriver automatically export to a big query dataset through terraform.

I have currently defined a logging sink referencing  and a big query dataset; which the logging sink references. However the dataset appears to be empty. Is there something I am missing here?

This is what my terraform code looks like currently:

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "stackdriver_logging" {
    dataset_id     = "stackdriver_logs"
    friendly_name  = "stackdriver_logs"
    location       = "US"
    project        = google_project.project.project_id    
}

resource "google_logging_project_sink" "big_query" {
  name                   = "${google_project.project.project_id}-_big_query-sink"
  project                = google_project.project.project_id
  destination            = "bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/${google_project.project.project_id}/datasets/${google_bigquery_dataset.stackdriver_logging.dataset_id}"
  unique_writer_identity = true
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "bq_log_writer" {
  member  = google_logging_project_sink.big_query.writer_identity
  role    = "roles/bigquery.dataEditor"
  project = google_project.project.project_id
}
```

Comment: Assuming it's setup correctly, it can still take a while for your logs to appear. When I tried this myself I think it took about 6 hours. Possibly it's related to the volume of logs you have, my guess is more logs would appear faster.

Comment: @Hitobat, 
From looking at my config, does it seem like it should be working? (assuming logs are being produced within stackdriver)